# vim omnifunc popup on keypress

Tags: vim, keypress, omnicomplete

I am making my .vimrc. Basically I want my omnifunc menu to popup on any keypress while in insert mode. The basic idea is to 
`cnoremap <C-x><C-o> <any key>`

At some point I will probably limit it to the alphabet if I can. And then I will probably limit it to be the second or third letter of a word.
So,  how can I remap all (alphabetic)keys to C-x C-o?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591822/calling-omnicompletion-for-every-keypress-in-vim

Comment: I was thinking of using the `getchar ()` function with something like `if getchar () = [a-z]; then popup menu;` but I don't know how to use it like that.